# Woocommerce add-to-cart template in child theme ignored

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The thing is that with using Advanced custom fields I have to retrieve link added to custom field in each product page, so that, when user clicks on "Add to Cart", it sends him to webpage which was provided in the custom field.

I seem to try it in different ways, like this https://docs.woothemes.com/document/override-loop-template-and-show-quantities-next-to-add-to-cart-buttons . The problem there is that the template path is ignored. I did it like there was said: wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php - the template is really ignored by WooCommerce!

Tested with some rubbish echoes, nothing shows up which could only mean that the template is ignored. The code in the add-to-cart.php is here http://pastebin.com/hLhwWggh

That template is fully ignored, I don't know what to do about it. And maybe there is something which would not work within the template itself?

Comment: For me, a `my-theme/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php` overrides just fine. My shop loop shows `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_field()` since I don't have ACF installed. Two things to check: your theme and plugins are modifying the theme's folder name... it's `woocommerce` by default, but can be changed. Also, under WooCommerce>System Status>Tools be sure that "Template Debug Mode" is *not* checked.

Comment: Also, this might be pedantic, but WooCommerce has a product type called "external" that redirects the add to cart button to the external url, which sounds exactly like what you are doing.

Comment: @helgatheviking Found on System status, that template was out-dated. Updated that, so I am now left with: http://pastebin.com/5hqbBUmX, changed esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) to esc_url(get_field('buy_link')) , still doesn't work, - sends back to the product page and shows that it is added to cart.

Comment: And template debug mode is disabled.

Comment: Still haven't found solution to why that template is not even used, even it seems that it overrides template from woocommerce plugin templates.
Could even do a syntax error, still - no nothing.

Comment: Next step is just classic debug procedure: disable all other plugins. you can't switch themes because the theme is what is the problem here, but you can disable/comment out everything in `functions.php`. You must have something that is interfering in the default behavior.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thanks for your assistance! Boss showed me the correct template that that single product page uses. Was kinda surprised and without any clue, why. This can be closed now!

Comment: I always advise clients to avoid overriding the add to cart templates. 95% of changes can be added via action/filter system. The add to cart templates are just too sensitive.

Comment: And you can't "close" questions. If you have a solution, you can post that as an "answer" and eventually accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: @helgatheviking From my experience, some css rules written in style.css of some popular themes... are just too frustrating. I could sometimes rewrite EXACTLY the same, save and changes are dropped which before worked. But that's not the topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed a special Variation Plugin when i enable `AJAX` "Add to Cart" then the quantity in woocommerce will not work.

When i disable `AJAX` all things worked perfectly!

----stooni